# XJC xsd to jaxb generation - how to ignore includes (not imports)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

Problem statement: I have between 50 to 60 xsd files provided by a third party. All except 2 are including (not importing) 2 common xsd files as below -

```
<xsd:include schemaLocation="common1.xsd"/>
<xsd:include schemaLocation="common2.xsd"/>
```

All xsds including the common xsds are in the same folder. I am using XJC tool on them to generate jaxb java-code.

I tried creating and using episode file to avoid generation of the java-classes for the types defined in the 2 common xsds but i am not having success. The common xsds does not have a targetnamespace nor the include directive have the defaultnamespace attribute and so the generated episode does not have the namespace as in -

```
<jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::">
```

due to this when i try to generate jaxb from any main xsd i get an error as below and I am stuck at this point.

```
[ERROR] SCD "x-schema::" didnt match any schema component
```

Request someone to help.

Comment: Do these 2 XSDs have their own and different namespaces?

Comment: No, they do not have their own namespaces.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? - I'm having a similar issue here.

Comment: @Herter, Sorry for the late reply. No I did not find any right solution to this. However in order to get going what I did was created jaxb classes for each domain under its own individual packages which results in duplicate classes in each of the packages - a bad solution though.